# Como faço um SELECT em 2 ou mais Tabelas com 2 ou mais condições?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Estou com um problema em fazer um select com as seguintes condições:
Quero mostrar os dados quer sejam com a condição1 ou com a condição2

```
Select * tabela inner join tabela2 WHERE campo = 0 and campo2 = '' and campo3 or campo10 is NULL
```

Selecionar todos os campos da tabela onde condição1 ou com a condição dois.

Exemplo concreto:

```
select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id where AlvaraNumero = 0 and (AlvaraValidade='' or AlvaraValidade is Null or AlvaraValidade='0000-00-00') and
 (AlvaraAnexo='' or AlvaraAnexo is Null) and AcidenteNumero = 0 and (AcidenteValidade='' or AcidenteValidade is Null or AcidenteValidade='0000-00-00') and (AcidenteAnexo='' or AcidenteAnexo is Null) and SeguroNumero = 0 and (SeguroValidade='' or SeguroValidade is Null or SeguroValidade='0000-00-00' ) and (SeguroAnexo='' or SeguroAnexo is Null) and 
InstaladorNumero = 0 and (InstaladorValidade='' or InstaladorValidade is Null or InstaladorValidade='0000-00-00') and (InstaladorAnexo='' or InstaladorAnexo is Null)
//Quero acrescentar esta segunda condição
or MedicaValidade is NULL or MedicaAnexo is NULL or ProjectistaNumero is NULL or 
 ProjectistaValidade is NULL or ProjectistaAnexo is NULL or GasNumero is NULL or GasValidade is NULL or GasAnexo is NULL or SoldadorNumero is NULL or SoldadorValidade is NULL or SoldadorAnexo is NULL or MecanicoValidade is NULL or MecanicoNumero
 is NULL or MecanicoAnexo is NULL or ClasSoldadorNumero Is NULL or ClasSoldadorValidade is NULL or ClasSoldadorAnexo is NULL order by tb_trabalhador.id
```

Comment: Especifique melhor o que você está tentando fazer, a qual tabela os campos pertencem e oque você quer selecionar com quais condições...

Comment: mostrar os dados desses select.
Com duas condiçoes possiveis para seres mostradas

Comment: Dá erro? não vem os dados esperados? Qual é o problema?

Comment: Não ma aparecem os dados esperados.
Por isso calculo que seja algo de errado na condição

Comment: @user3253195 A minha resposta visa melhorar o teu entendimento sobre como deves colocar a tua consulta. Mas presumo pela tua consulta actual que o teu problema estás nas últimas condições `OR` cujas mesmas vão acabar por subscrever as condições `AND`.

Comment: realmente não da pra entender o que exatamente você está tentando perguntar, mas a resposta do @Zuul deve ser capaz de tirar qualquer duvida que você tenha

Comment: edit: desculpa, agora que vi. a pergunta foi postada a 7 meses atras. vacilei :v eu lia a data no modelo americano, que coincide com hoje, 03/11

Answer (score 25, accepted):

O teu exemplo concreto está um pouco confuso e parece ter pouco a haver com a lógica que estás a apresentar.

## Teu exemplo lógico

Dado não estares a apresentar detalhes sobre cada tabela e de que forma se relacionam, posso deixar algumas dicas para construíres a consulta com base na lógica apresentada:

> Select * tabela inner join tabela2 WHERE campo = 0 and campo2 = '' and campo3 or campo10 is NULL

Deves dar um alias às tabelas para identificares correctamente onde se encontram as colunas:

```sql
SELECT t1.* FROM minhaTabela t1 WHERE t1.meuCampo = 0
```

<sup>Estamos a dizer que a coluna `meuCampo` está na tabela `minhaTabela` através do alias `t1`.</sup>

Se pretendes usar `OR`, deves envolver a sub-condição em `()`:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.campoXpto                            # selecciona tudo da t1 e campos da t2
FROM minhaTabela t1                                  # identifica minhaTabela como t1
INNER JOIN minhaTabela2 t2 ON (t1.campo = t2.campo)  # match com tabela t2
WHERE t1.meuCampo = 0                                # condição #1
AND t1.meuCampo2 = ''                                # condição #2
AND (t1.meuCampo3 IS NULL OR t1.meuCampo10 IS NULL)  # condição #3
```

<sup>Estamos a dizer na condição #3 que o `meuCampo3` ou o `meuCampo10` tem que ser `NULL`.</sup>

## Tua consulta real

A tua consulta na forma que a tens na pergunta está confusa e não clarifica onde se encontram as colunas nem de que forma pretendes validar a informação para recolher ou não os registos.

Deves ver a base-de-dados como uma pessoa com quem estás a ter uma conversa e colocas perguntas:

> Base-de-dados, dá-me aí registos da tabela X onde existam colunas que estejam com valores Y e que tenham uma relação com a tabela J!

Mesmo depois de ter indentado a tua consulta, ficam muitas dúvidas:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tb_detalhe_trabalhador
INNER JOIN tb_trabalhador ON tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id
INNER JOIN tb_equipamentos ON tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id
WHERE AlvaraNumero = 0
AND (AlvaraValidade='' or AlvaraValidade is Null OR AlvaraValidade='0000-00-00')
AND (AlvaraAnexo='' OR AlvaraAnexo is Null) 
AND AcidenteNumero = 0
AND (AcidenteValidade='' OR AcidenteValidade is Null OR AcidenteValidade='0000-00-00') 
AND (AcidenteAnexo='' OR AcidenteAnexo is Null) 
AND SeguroNumero = 0 
AND (SeguroValidade='' OR SeguroValidade is Null OR SeguroValidade='0000-00-00') 
AND (SeguroAnexo='' or SeguroAnexo is Null) 
AND InstaladorNumero = 0 
AND (InstaladorValidade='' OR InstaladorValidade is Null OR InstaladorValidade='0000-00-00') 
AND (InstaladorAnexo='' OR InstaladorAnexo is Null) 
OR MedicaValidade is NULL 
OR MedicaAnexo is NULL 
OR ProjectistaNumero is NULL 
OR ProjectistaValidade is NULL 
OR ProjectistaAnexo is NULL 
OR GasNumero is NULL 
OR GasValidade is NULL 
OR GasAnexo is NULL 
OR SoldadorNumero is NULL 
OR SoldadorValidade is NULL 
OR SoldadorAnexo is NULL 
OR MecanicoValidade is NULL 
OR MecanicoNumero is NULL 
OR MecanicoAnexo is NULL 
OR ClasSoldadorNumero Is NULL 
OR ClasSoldadorValidade is NULL 
OR ClasSoldadorAnexo is NULL
ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id
```

- A que tabela pertencem os campos:

  Quando fazes consultas em mais que uma tabela, deves sempre indicar a que tabela pertence a coluna:

  ```sql
  tb_detalhe_trabalhador.meuCampo
  ```

  ou com alias `t1` para a tabela `tb_detalhe_trabalhador`:

  ```sql
  t1.meuCampo
  ```
- As condições do tipo X ou Y devem estar sempre protegidas por `()` para evitar má interpretação das mesmas:

  As últimas condições são `OR`, mas estão foram de `()` o que quer dizer que pretendes registos onde X e Y e Z ou J.
  O J vai subscrever o X e Y e Z.

  Basicamente estás a dizer que se uma daquelas colunas no `OR` for `NULL`, queres o registo.

Comment: O meu problema não estava propriamente na forma como estava a consulta mas sim como estava a pedir os dados.
Sempre que tenho datas coloco (AcidenteValidade='' OR AcidenteValidade is Null OR AcidenteValidade='0000-00-00') 
para mostrar.

Comment: Uma resposta depois da outra, todas *consistentemente excelentes*. Ainda que o problema do OP estivesse em outro lugar, a explicação é tão detalhada que não tem como não aprender um bocado e avançar sozinho em direção a uma solução. +1 é pouco :)