# Como selecionar várias colunas utilizando o prefixo da tabela só uma vez?

Tags: mysql, sql

Na condição de modelo relacional, eu tenho que especificar o prefixo da tabela, estou certo?

Exemplo: `SELECT c.nome, c.idade, a.nome, a.idade FROM`...

O que eu queria saber, é se não tem como fazer algo assim:

`SELECT c(nome, idade), a(nome, idade) FROM`...

Tem como dar essa "agilizada" no código, ou o único jeito é pôr prefixo em tudo?

Comment: Diferente disto, acho que só mesmo o `SELECT c.*, a.* FROM...`

Comment: Essa é a resposta, @ismael

Comment: Não é possivel fazer isso. O banco vai tentar achar uma função c e uma função a nesse exemplo: `SELECT c(nome, idade), a(nome, idade) FROM`

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Mas foi exatamente esse o problema. Não estava perguntando ao pé da letra, mas algo semelhante, entende? Mas acho que não tem mesmo =(

Comment: @ismael Eu estava tentando fugir dessa opção, pois acho que consome mais recursos, não?

Comment: Como disse o Ismael `c( nome, idade )` deve ser `c.*`

Comment: Utilizar o * indiscriminadamente realmente vai consumir mais processamento e banda de rede, já que TODOS os campos das tabelas (de sua consulta) serão requisitados. Além disso, influenciará diretamente no índice escolhido pelo SGDB para realizar a consulta. Pode ter consequências ruins ao trabalhar com Views também. Particularmente, sempre declaro todos os campos.

Comment: Também porque alterações na tabela podem 'quebrar' aqueles códigos com `*`

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelos esclarecimentos.  Vou declarar tudo com prefixo mesmo. Valeu! =)

Comment: Não há como fazer isso. Cada campo da tabela retornado no `SELECT` é único, por isso tem que prefixar com o aliás ou nome da tabela se houver mais de um campo com o mesmo nome nas tabelas usadas no `FROM`. Usar * não é uma boa opção, como já mencionou o @ismael . Mas essa "agilizada" que você comentou pode não ser um esforço tão grande, uma vez que você monta a query uma vez e não fica alterando toda hora, vale a pena fazer uma query bem legível, fácil de entender e que não vá gerar problemas depois.

Comment: @inovapixel Olá, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor solução para seu problema, será realmente a declaração campo a campo com seus devidos **`Alias`**.

Obviamente você poderá utilizar o caractere coringa *, considere a sintaxe:

> [PREFIXO].* ou
>   [NOME DA TABELA].*

Considerando que **TODOS** os campos serão invocados, seu caso ficaria:

`SELECT c.*, a.* FROM...`

---

### [Usando aliases de tabela](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)

"A legibilidade de uma instrução `SELECT` pode ser aprimorada, atribuindo um alias a uma tabela, que também é conhecido como **nome de correlação ou variável de intervalo**. Um alias de tabela pode ser atribuído com ou sem a palavra-chave AS:

```
table_name AS table alias
table_name table_alias
```

Obs. Se um alias for atribuído a uma tabela, todas as referências explícitas à tabela na instrução do `Transact-SQL` precisarão usar o alias; não o nome de tabela."

Alguns posts correlacionados

[Prefixos em Sentença SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69492/prefixos-em-senten%C3%A7a-sql)
[Como faço um SELECT em 2 ou mais Tabelas com 2 ou mais condições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8822/como-fa%C3%A7o-um-select-em-2-ou-mais-tabelas-com-2-ou-mais-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es)