# Selecionar campos a retornar em uma SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Como consigo numa única linha de instrução SQL, tipo `SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON xxxxx`, sendo que o retorno desejado seria formado por todos os campos(colunas) de `table1` e apenas um campo(coluna) de `table2`?

Comment: Olá Ronilson, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 3):

Você vai conseguir prefixando (Alias) as tabelas:

```
SELECT TBL1.*, TBL2.seu_campo FROM table1 TBL1
INNER JOIN table2 TBL2 ON xxxxx
```

Relacionada
[Como selecionar várias colunas utilizando o prefixo da tabela só uma vez?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192380/46243)

Comment: Simples assim!!! Obrigado **@Ismael**